# Oracle SQL - Issue with inserting values into columns and foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, foreign-keys

I have a table which contains 2 foreign keys from 2 seperate tables as well as normal columns. I have managed to insert the data into the foreign keys however I am having trouble inserting data into the normal columns. Here is my statement

```
INSERT INTO Emp_LC
(EmpID, fName, sName, lCCode, Date)
SELECT * FROM
((SELECT EmpID FROM Employees WHERE jobDesc = 'Driver' OR Employees.jobDesc = 'DRIVER')), 
((SELECT lCCode FROM LicCerts WHERE Desc = 'Driving Licence'));
```

I want to add a value for fName, sName and Date to this statement but I cant figure out where to place them. I think I need 'VALUES' somewhere within the statement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these come from the `employees` table, add them to the subquery and the outer query:

```
INSERT INTO Emp_LC(EmpID, fName, sName, lCCode, Date)
    SELECT EmpId, fName, sName, lCCode, date
    FROM (SELECT EmpID, fName, sName
          FROM Employees
          WHERE jobDesc = 'Driver' OR Employees.JOBDESCRIPTION = 'DRIVER'
         ) CROSS JOIN 
         (SELECT lCCode, date
          FROM LicCerts
          WHERE Desc = 'Driving Licence'
         );
```

This assumes `date` comes from `LicCerts`.

Comment: Thanks, but for the    date    how would I go about manually typing in to the statement eg (03-JAN-15)?

Comment: @Logic210: use a date literal: `date '2015-01-03'`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062